# Not taking parameters for mysql stored procedure c#

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure in MySQL database.
This procedure is taking 6 input parameters and 2 Output parameters.

I need to call this Stored Procedure from my c# application.
Below is my code:

```
if (_MySqlConnectionSMS1.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                _MySqlConnectionSMS1.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand sqlcmd1 = new MySqlCommand("usp_Data_Insert", _MySqlConnectionSMS1))
            {
                sqlcmd1.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@in_ApplicationName", "AEM"));
                sqlcmd1.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@in_ApplicationCode", "AEM"));
                sqlcmd1.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@in_NTLogin", ntid));
                sqlcmd1.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@in_SMSMsg", Message));
                sqlcmd1.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@in_Workcell", ""));
                sqlcmd1.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@in_SMSTime", System.DateTime.Now));

                sqlcmd1.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@out_Result", MySqlDbType.Int32));
                sqlcmd1.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@out_Message", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
                sqlcmd1.Parameters["@out_Result"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                sqlcmd1.Parameters["@out_Message"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                sqlcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                int Status = Convert.ToInt16(sqlcmd1.Parameters["@out_Result"].Value);
                string retMessage = Convert.ToString(sqlcmd1.Parameters["@out_Result"].Value);
            }
```

But while sqlcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(). I am getting below error:

Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE TE_SMS.usp_SendSMS_Insert; expected 8, got 0

I have even checked the parameters in command before it's execution. And they are available in Parameter list.
What am I missing here.?

Comment: Do you not need to do sqlcmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; ?

Comment: I did added it before calling this code. but I missed that I have create the new instance of that command...

Comment: So is this fixed now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

Add the below line before adding input/output parameters to the sql command object.

sqlcmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: I did added it before calling this code. but Imissed that I have create the new instance of that command...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
            sqlcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue(new MySqlParameter("@in_ApplicationName", "AEM"));
            sqlcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue(new MySqlParameter("@in_ApplicationCode", "AEM"));
            sqlcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue(new MySqlParameter("@in_NTLogin", ntid));
            sqlcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue(new MySqlParameter("@in_SMSMsg", Message));
            sqlcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue(new MySqlParameter("@in_Workcell", ""));
            sqlcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue(new MySqlParameter("@in_SMSTime", System.DateTime.Now));

            sqlcmd1.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@out_Result", MySqlDbType.Int32){Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });
            sqlcmd1.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@out_Message", MySqlDbType.VarChar){Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });
            sqlcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

To get results

```
int result1 = int.Parse(sqlcmd1.Parameters["@out_Result"].value.ToString())
string result2 = sqlcmd1.Parameters["@out_Message"].value.ToString();
```